# What makes an object a writable stream in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I've been working recently with express and mongoose under nodejs, and I've found I'm able to do some things that don't seem to work as I would expect. When I generate an aggregation query in mongoose, I'm given an `Aggregate` object (ex. `const aggregation = Foo.aggregate(pipeline).cursor()`. By executing this object (`aggregation.exec()`), I'm given an `AggregationCursor`, which the mongoose documentation explicitly states inherits from `Readable` and as such is a readable stream which can be piped to a writable stream.

This is where my confusion starts. I have an express `Response` object `res` which inherits from the nodejs `http.ServerResponse`, itself inheriting from `http.OutgoingMessage`, none of which seem to inherit `Writable`. The line `aggregation.exec().pipe(res)` functions properly however, piping the aggregation query result to the response object. How does this function? I see that the `http.ServerResponse` class has a `write` method, but is this enough? Is it enough to implement `write` and emit the proper events in order for an object to be considered a `Writable` even without any inheritance?

I get the feeling this has to do with the fact that javascript is a prototyping language, so nothing really 'inherits' it simply looks up the prototype chain to find properties, but I'm not sure. Does anyone know how this works?

Comment: The linked question answers this somewhat. If you view the source of `OutgoingMessage`, it seems `stream.Stream` is extended as in the first method of the answer there.

Answer (score 0):

In Node.js, an object is considered a writable stream when it implements the `Writable` interface provided by the Node.js core `stream` module. To make an object a writable stream, you need to ensure that it adheres to this interface, which consists of specific methods and event handling.

Here's a basic outline of what's required:

1. **Implement the Writable Stream Interface:**
   Your object should implement the following methods and events:

   - `write(chunk, encoding, callback)`: This method is called when data should be written to the stream. It should process the provided `chunk` and invoke the `callback` when the write operation is complete.
   - `end([chunk[, encoding]][, callback])`: This method is used to signal the end of writing. You can optionally provide a final `chunk` and `encoding` to write before ending, and a `callback` to be called when the stream is fully ended.
   - `on('finish', callback)`: This event is emitted when the stream has finished writing. You can attach your custom logic to the `finish` event.
2. **Handle Errors:**
   A writable stream should also handle errors gracefully by emitting an `'error'` event when an error occurs during writing. You can use the `emit` method to emit this event with an error object.

By implementing these methods and handling errors, your custom object can behave as a writable stream in Node.js, allowing you to write data to it in a stream-like fashion.

Comment: It's chaptGPT but looks valid

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned